# The provided API key is invalid/Geocoding-Python

Tags: python, api, geocoding

I got a geocoding API Key , but when I put it in my program it gives me this error : `{ "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }`
and I tried to make a new one and the same thing happened

My Program:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
import json

service = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=My_API_Key_is_here'

while True :
  address = input('Enter a location:')
  if len(address) < 1 :
      break
  url = service + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address' : address})

  print('Retrieving',url)
  urll = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  data = urll.read().decode()
  print('Retrieved',len(data),'Characters')

  try:
      js = json.loads(data)
  except :
      js = None 

  if not js or 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK' :
      print('===Faield===')
      print (data)
      continue

  lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
  lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
  print('lat',lat,"lng",lng)
  location = js["results"][0]["formatted_address"]  
  print(location)
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It can take 10-30 minutes for a newly generated API key to become active

Comment: I have generated this API key before 24 hour

Comment: Make sure you are using GeoCoding and not GeoLocation API Key. I believe this is also billable.
```{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}```

Comment: I am sure that it's a "Geocoding Key", but I didn't add a payment method to my account so..?